# Sort MYSQL TABLES using a button with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sorting

I'm just wondering if it's possible to sort (ascending and descending) MYSQL tables(rows) using a button with JQuery. I did a research already but I haven't found any accurate solution. If anyone knows how to do it, can you share your codes please? Thank you.

Comment: too broad to answer, as it can be implemented in many ways, show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Avinash I'm not familiar with JQuery so I haven't done anything. I've been doing a lot of research but I didn't get any answer so far. I did sorting using PHP but not with JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to extract the results of your MySQL database and you want to sort the ascending or descending tables. The best way to achieve your purpose is to use [Datatable](http://www.datatables.net/)

And more precisely [Server-side processing](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)